# Objective C - difference between dictionaries and arrays?

Tags: objective-c

in Objective C - what is the difference between dictionaries and arrays? Are dictionaries used with key : value (where Key can be any object), and arrays are id : value (where id is an integer)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array**

In Objective-C, an array is a type of collection which can store object types. It can store any type of objects. Objects stored in an array are linked to their index number.

eg. if you create an array and insert the first object, it will be stored in "index 0"
and, the index number will keep on increasing from 0,1,2....n

Use "NSMutableArray" to create an array that can be modified.

example,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"Tom"];
[array addObject:@"Cat"];
```

So, at index 0, you will have "Tom". And, at index 1, you will have "Cat".

**Dictionary**

In Objective-C, a dictionary is a type of collection that stores "key-value" pairs.
The "key" is of type ID, so you can enter any object as key for a value.

Use "NSMutableDictionary" to create a dictionary that can be modified.

example,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:@"Tom" forkey:@"name"];
[dictionary setObject:@"Cat" forKey:@"animal"];
```

The key difference between array and dictionary is the sequence of the objects gets changed in a dictionary, while in an array the sequence of objects stored is SEQUENTIAL.

**[EDIT]**

Since there has been quite a discussion with regard to this answer, I will make it clear that the array does NOT get re-created as some comments say.

The size of array/dictionary gets dynamically increased to accomodate the new elements in the colletion.

Comment: NSMutableArray internally recreates the array when you modify it. It is a very expensive operation. It is a good idea to not use NSMutableArray unless it is really required.

Comment: NSMutableArray should only recreate the array if it grows beyond the current capacity. Otherwise it should not. Also it should be pretty smart in how it grows the capacity (but I did not verify that the current implementation is). If you use it correctly (by setting an appropriate capacity) it should be extremely cheap to use.

Comment: Actually, after a little investigation is seems to me that `NSMutableArray` does not recreate the array at all. It seem to use a deque like ADT internally.

Comment: NSArray is not always implemented as a C array, there has been some investigation of NSArray that strongly suggest that for different sizes the implementation changes. Even with a C array with virtual memory extending blocks of memory is cheep, this is because the real memory addresses used are different from the virtual address used and so a single block of virtual memory can be created from smaller blocks of randomly located memory, I don't know how this works on iOS with no VM, maybe its just employs memory paging like a virtual memory system but not the writing to disk.

Comment: @NathanDay what you say could be done but only if the array is allocated on a page boundary and only by using specialized calls to the operating system. This is not what happens and it's only beneficial anyway except for extremely large arrays (several dozens of GiB, probably). What used to happens was that if the array is mutable (aka NSMutableArray) it started with a plain C array but eventually became a deque above a certain number of elements. It seems the most modern version always use a deque, but I did not analyze the whole source yet.

Comment: My understanding is malloc will do this if the the amount of memory allocated is large enough, and page sizes are about 4k in size not Gbytes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory).